# Como hago para que mis checkbox mantengan su estado checked cuando se recarga la busqueda

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

mi problema es que tengo unos checkboxs en una tabla y cuando le doy checked, y quiero buscar en mi barra de busqueda, al momento que me muestra el resultado de la busqueda, y vuelvo a mi tabla original se borra el estado "Checked".
He intentado con sessionstorage pero aun asi no me funciona del todo bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $idchk+=1;
?>          
        <tr>  

            <td>
                <input name='checkimp[]' id='<?php echo $idchk ?>' type='checkbox' value='<?php echo $fila['id'] ?>' 
                onclick="if(this.checked)sessionStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else sessionStorage.removeItem(this.id);">
            </td>

            <td><?php echo $fila['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['nombre'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['telef1'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['telef2'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['telef3'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['distrito'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['direccion'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['nrocasa'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['nrodpto'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['referencia'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['urb'] ?></td>                


            <td><input type="text" name="cosas" id='cosas'></td>

            <td>

            <a class='btn btn-danger' href='#'onclick='preguntar("<?php echo $fila['id'] ?>")'>
                <i class='icon-trash'></i>
            </a>
            <a class='btn btn-info' href='editar.php?edit="<?php echo $fila['id'] ?>"'>
                <i class='icon-edit'></i>
            </a>


            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>
                        <i class='icon-print'></i>
                    </button> 


            </td>

        </tr><script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML='Valores checkeados:<br>'; 
    for (var i=0; i<sessionStorage.length; i++){ 
        var key = sessionStorage.key(i); 
        document.getElementById(key).checked=1; 
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+=sessionStorage.getItem(key); 
    } 
    if(!i)document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+='ninguno'; </script>
```

Cabe rescatar que mi busqueda es con ajax, y no se recarga la pagina, pero si se pudiera mantener cuando se recarge tambien seria genial, pero no se como puedo hacerlo, muchas gracias de antemano.

```html
$(buscar_datos());

function buscar_datos(consulta){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'buscar.php ' ,
  type: 'POST' ,
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {consulta: consulta},
 })
 .done(function(respuesta){
  $('#datos').html(respuesta);
 })
 .fail(function(){
  console.log("error");
 });
}


$(document).on('keyup','#caja_busqueda', function(){
 var valor = $(this).val();
 if (valor != "") {
  buscar_datos(valor);
 }else{
  buscar_datos();
 }
});
```

Comment: Que tiene dentro  `buscar.php`?

Comment: Dentro de mi "buscar.php" esta : `if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
     $q = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
             $query = "SELECT * FROM donadors 
                    where nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'
                    OR telef1 like '%".$q."%'
                    OR telef2 LIKE '%".$q."%'
                    OR telef3 LIKE '%".$q."%'
                    OR direccion LIKE '%".$q."%'
                    or nrocasa LIKE '%".$q."%'
                    OR distrito LIKE '%".$q."%' limit 15";


    }` Es mas que nada mi consulta para la busqueda

Comment: debes guardar su varlor en una variable de session